# TestFlight and Xcode5

Tags: xcode, testflight

Can someone please post a step by step guide on how to distribute an app for testing using TestFlight and XCode5 that is complete, works, and simple? I already read the TestFlight and Apple docs and I still don't get it.

Comment: "I don't get it" isn't useful.  How far along the process did you get?  Where did you get stuck?  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I just did it:

In Xcode5..

1. Select a real device at the top, (i.e. iOS device) instead of a simulator.
2. Select the Product / Archive menu option
3. This will generate an archive and open the Organiser on the Archives tab.
4. Click 'Distribute…'
5. Choose 'Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment'
6. Click 'Next'
7. Choose a provisioning profile from the list
8. Click 'Export'
9. Choose where you want to save it. (I didn't select 'save for enterprise distribution')

You now have a .ipa file to upload to TestFlight

Answer (score -1):

This is best practice for distribute app.Please see below step...

1>Go to Project,Archive app.

2>In archive,click on distribute.

3>Click on save for enterprise or ad hoc deployment and save ipa file to your desktop

4>open https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/ and login

5>After login,click on upload your build button

6>Next click on drop your ipa file.Select .ipa file from desktop and upload it.

7>Selct provisioning profile by tick check mark and click update and notify button.

8>After clicking update and notify,Please click on share build button below update and notify.

9>Also you can see this share option by clicking permission on right hand menu.

10>After clicking share button,you need to provide your email id for showing testflight app in your mail inbox.

11>open test flight mail into your device and click on install button.

12>app automatically open testflight in your device,Please login with testflight,click on install profile button

13>After all click on app just you upload,click on install button. app will automatically install in your device.

Please tell me in case of any query regarding this.

Thanks